# Launching the app directly on clicking deep-link

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm using `branch.io` in my project for deep-linking. On click of the deep-link, the app is not getting launched directly instead it's showing the list of apps. Then I need to click my app in order to open it. I'm testing on Oreo(API level 27) device. Below is a piece of manifest code.

```
         <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:targetApi="m">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="xxx-alternate.app.link"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="xxx.test-app.link"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="xxx.app.link"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to ensure for a deeplink to directly open your app:

1. The `intent-filter` for the App link has the autoverify option set to true (which I see is set in your case)
2. The SHA-256 key you have uploaded on the Branch dashboard is the same SHA-256 key that is used to sign your APK file. (Make sure if you are testing against a debug build to use the SHA-256 key from the debug keystore)

If correctly setup, the app link should correctly open your app. This behavior was updated since Android API level 23 and above.

You can check if the link domain is correctly linked to your application [here](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator). On entering the details and clicking `Test Statement` it should state "Success! Host `<your domain>` grants app deep linking to `<App Package Name>`" if correctly linked.

PS: If you update your SHA-256 key on Branch dashboard, it might take a few hours for Google to scrap the asset-link file hosted by Branch.

Comment: But Amruta, youtube, flipkart applications are launching directly on clicking the link. its not routing from browser.

Comment: @A2N apologies for my previous answer. Added an updated response. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Amruta, The system which is used to generate signed APK is not configured with its SHA key in branch. will do the same and check it out.

Comment: Hi Amruta, i have added the prod keystore file's sha256 in branch for the live domain. In google's tools its showing successfully host and its been 16+ hours now. but still its not directly launching the app.

Comment: I checked in my app settings and got to know that user can modify the link openings from android 8+