# How to disable disambiguation dialog when opening Branch.io deeplink

Tags: android, branch.io

I have followed the steps to setup deep links using Branch.io in my app and I successfully received my first deep link through an SMS.

My problem is that when I open the link I am not directly taken to the link destination (website or app), but to a disambiguation dialog, exactly like in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpaByLW_ctw&t=3m21s

Apparently this can ben avoided by linking the Digital Asset Links file to a given URL.

[image]

When I check this with the App Links Assistant, an error saying that the file is malformed, which is not true. When I click the link I get the exact same content as shown in the preview, but the SHA246 fingerprint value is missing (even though I filled the "SHA256 Fingerprint" field in Branch.io dashboard, under "Links Settings", "Android", "SHA256 Cert Fingerprints").

How can I properly link this deep link to my Android app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today it takes around 30 minutes for Branch to update the **.well-known/assetslinks.json** file.
This got me confused and made me switch my original SHA256 fingerprints (which was the valid one) for several other fingerprint, ending up with an invalid one.

Also note that you won't get any error in the dashboard if you provide an ill-formed SHA256.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are following the above method to link your Branch link domain to the asset-link file. Branch hosts the asset link file for you.

All you need to do is enable App Links in the Link Settings on the Branch dashboard and add your SHA256 certificate. Branch will then host the asset-link file for you which will be scraped by Google.

To know more on how to configure app links for your app you can refer to the Branch documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#configure-app).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759439/launching-the-app-directly-on-clicking-deep-link/48771253#48771253) is a post for more information on the prerequisites for the deeplinking to work.

Comment: _I am not sure why you are following the above method to link your Branch link domain to the asset-link file._ Because I am getting the disambiguation dialog while it should not appear. I think that this problem is related to the SHA256 fingerprint that is not properly bound to Branch. This is what I get when querying my DAL file in Branch (at https://myapp.app.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json : [{"relation":["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],"target":{"namespace":"my_namespace","package_name":"my.package.name","sha256_cert_fingerprints":[]}}]
The fingerprints array is empty :(

Comment: Have you added the SHA256 cert in the Branch dashboard?

Comment: Yes I did, under "Links Settings", "Android", "SHA256 Cert Fingerprints"

Comment: Can you enter the details on this site (https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) and generate a test statement. It should state "Success! Host <your domain> grants app deep linking to <App Package Name>" if correctly linked. If you continue having issues can you please write into `integrations@branch.io`?

Comment: This ends up with an error : No app deep linking permission found for ... I just sent an email to integrations@branch.io with more details