# Android app links have been verified. But, still disambiguation dialog shows up

Tags: android

When I click on the link: https://example.com/abcd on android version 6/7/8 it shows disambiguation dialog. We have already verified domain by placing json at: https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json. I've done everything as per the documentation and still the link doesn't open without disambiguation. Please help me find what I'm missing.

Code in manifest:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPattern="/abcd"
    />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable disambiguation dialog when opening Branch.io deeplink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869630/how-to-disable-disambiguation-dialog-when-opening-branch-io-deeplink)

Comment: @MartinZeitler i don't think its a  [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869630/how-to-disable-disambiguation-dialog-when-opening-branch-io-deeplink) as links from branch.io differ from app links in who owns the verification process and how they are resolved.

Comment: @RandomAspirer there is nothing different, no matter the host-name, because this happens on the device.

Comment: you need to create a json file with the SHA256 cert for the release key - and upload the json to your site. Check https://android.jlelse.eu/avoid-android-disambiguation-dialog-using-app-link-digital-assets-link-434395e1ed30

Comment: @Tejas B Have you figured out what was a problem?

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party but I too experienced the disambiguation always popping up. For those who haven't managed to resolve this yet (or to come), go to Logcat and search for "IntentFilterIntentOp". You should be seeing something like `Verification 8 complete. Success:true. Failed hosts:.` This may fail (`Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:8 scheme:"https" hosts:"example.co.za" package:"za.co.example.qa".)` if you've uploaded your assetlinks.json file to one domain whilst it's not accessible on other or subdomains that you've registered in your intent-filter.

It's also worth mentioning that your App would have to have been launched at least once before in order for "IntentFilterIntentOp" to perform the necessary verification. Accessing a link via App Link Testing in Android Studio should thereafter automatically open your app without the disambiguation dialog.

Answer (score 6):

**update as of 2021 with Android 12:**

Android changed web intent resolution policy that effects link handling, if you follow all the new requirements your app will be given a chance if not browser will handle those, more on this here:
[web intent resolution requirements](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#web-intent-resolution)

/////////////////////Below behavior might still apply today//////////////////////

The Caveat here is if you install the app through playstore the default `"link-handling policy"` of the application with registered domains like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is set to "Handle in the app", which will open the app directly subject to intent filter verification without any disambiguation dialogues.

If you install the app by means other than playstore like through adb even though you sign it with keystore the default `link handling policy` is set to "Always ask" which will show disambiguation dialog even though the intent-filter verification passes for your app link.

Comment: Is there a supporting documentation for this?

Comment: there is no specific documentation on what install medium sets what policy but there is documentation for testing "link-handling policy" which i did and came to the above conclusion that i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, however, it works for me when installing a debug build via Gradle. It seems like it needs some time to link the app and the domain, which is why I believed that this answer could be correct before.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot that's also a possibility.

Comment: I can confirm that this is exactly what I experienced. Installed via slack, went to "Always ask". Installed from the store, wen to "Handle in the app".

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add autoVerify="true":

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPattern="/abcd"
    />
```

Comment: autoVerify="true" is added. but, still the issue persists.

Comment: Please check logcat. There must be something like:
    IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification [some_number] complete. Success:[true/false]

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this, both http and https:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="www.oschina.net"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="www.oschina.net"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="my.oschina.net"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="my.oschina.net"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue. Take a look at your sha256 fingerprint. If you test applinks with debug version of the app then you have to place the fingerprint for debug version. You can do it in Android Studio - Tools - App Links Assistant - Associate website.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app with Android studio, it is installed a debug APK on your device which might match the live config (which is for release APK or bundle) on your branch dashboard.

To handle de the debug (or test) mode in branch this is what I did

1. Setup test configuration in your branch dashboard:

   - On the top left on the dashboard there is a switch to access the test mode, click on it and fill the form for the test config.
   - Next create a debug link. The field values should be the same as for a live (release) mode link. the only difference the generated test link contains a prefix
     yourapp.*test-*app.link/xxxxx
2. Create two Android manifest files for each type of APK or bundle:

   - `app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` <- for debug APK or bundle
   - `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` <- for release APK or bundle
3. Do the Branch SDK setup on both two manifest files

You should now be able to use the debug link without the disambiguation prompt showing